# Бегущая дорожка на OpenGL

Tags: glut, разработка-игр, c++, opengl

Хочу сделать гонку как на тетрисе (ну вспоминайте), только 3D, правда возникла следующая проблема:
 не могу нарисовать бегущую дорожку =(
Есть кто сможет помочь?

P.S. я чайник, настоящий `solid`ный (`glutSolidTeapot(5);`) xD

Comment: Это как, уточните вопрос. Советую для начала прочитать пару хороших книжек, прежде чем браться за что-либо “серьезное”. 

Comment: в общем я знаком с opengl и графикой. до этого делал маленькие анимации, двигал руки, ноги, голову и т.д. в общем имею понятия, я в смысле чайник среди прогеров. 
перейдем к делу! сама задача состоит в том чтобы создать полноценный 3D клон гонки с тетриса, уже нарисовал машину, осталось нарисовать бегущую дорожку по оси xz в глубину монитора. заранее спасибо =)

Comment: Вы о tetris race - http://www.123chase.com/ru/tetris_race/2996
Дорожку можно изобразить в виде плоскости, которая будет вытягиваться вперед, вглубь экрана. Это очень просто сделать, если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: я думаю, мы поняли друг друга! представление имею как это будет выглядеть, мне нужен код...если вам не трудно, мб покажете мастер-класс?

Answer (score 1):

Построить плоскость как раз проще, чем установить камеру, настроить её вращение и нарисовать машину.
 Если я правильно тебя понял, тебе нужно это:

```
int width=10, length=1000;
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(width, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(width, 0, length);
glVertex3f(0, 0, length);
glEnd();
```

Надеюсь, у тебя матрицы правильно настроены. width и length устанавливаются в зависимости от масштаба.

Comment: спасибо всем большое!!! уже почти закончил=)))
если у кого есть исходники игр, буду рад ознакомиться с ней и узнать от вас что нибудь новенькое...yerden91@gmail.com
=)

Answer (score 0):

Можно узнать на какой стадии разработки вы сейчас находитесь? Вам необходимо изобразить двумерную плоскость, которая, растягиваясь вглубь экрана, будет представлять собой бегущую дорожку. Как рисовать полигоны и манипулировать их вершинами можно прочитать практически в любой литературе по OpenGL.  Но вам, мне кажется, ещё рано браться за такие проекты. Для начала неплохо будет немного подучить С++ на уровне переменных, функций, циклов и  массивов. Насчёт OpenGL  советую прочитать “суперкнигу” – почти что исчерпывающий источник по этой библиотеке, которую без труда можно отыскать на просторах сети. В качестве альтернативного варианта могу посоветовать движок Game Maker – неплохой инструмент для создания игр. “Кризиса” на нем, конечно, не напишешь, но для ваших задач подойдёт в самый раз. Сэкономите кучу времени.

Comment: Для начала неплохо будет немного подучить С++ на уровне переменных, функций, циклов и массивов.

 Это скорее C, чем C++.

    В качестве альтернативного варианта могу посоветовать движок Game Maker – неплохой инструмент для создания игр.
 Только он предназначен для 2D. 3D на нём делать возможно, но так же сложно, как и на OpenGL.

Comment: мне нужно именно на opengl написать! создал окно, установил освещение, установил камеру и настроил его вращение, нарисовал машину....осталось, нарисовать дорожку по xz в глубь по оси z и чтобы она двигалась...вот в чем суть моей проблемы! скинь те отрывок возможного кода, люди добрые!